# Can't sleep in owned house

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dragonborn

Completed the quest "Served Cold," but I can't sleep in any of the beds and I can't wait. When I try, I see the message: "You cannot sleep/wait while being asked to leave."

- When I execute `setcellownership DLC2RRSeverinHouse` this issue is not resolved.
- When I execute `player.isTrespassing`, the value is `0.00`
- When I execute `getStage DLC2RR02`, the value is `GetStage >> 200.0` (which is the completed stage for this quest)

Is there a way to fix this?

**UPDATE**

I've gone back to a previous save (before the Ashfallow Citadel), finished the quest again and find myself with the same results.

Comment: Could you please type `getstage DLC2RR02` in the console and add what it says into the question? That will tell us whether Served Cold has completed properly or not.

Comment: Does using `setownership` on the bed fix the problem?

Comment: I've already confirmed that I am the bed owner using `isowner`. It really doesn't seem to be an ownership issue, but a trespassing issue. However, I've verified that I'm not trespassing.

Answer (score 2):

This is a fairly late answer, so I hope your problem is fixed already.

Are you using the [Unofficial Dragonborn patch](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/31083/?)?

If not, please install it and try the pre-finish save again. The patch fixes a lot of developer bugs that Bethesda haven't got around to fixing. In this case it appears that the quest completion script fails to remove any previous trespassing effects and set full ownership. I'm fairly sure I've been able to sleep there when I last played that part of the game.